# Issue with webp image format in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Image Server infrastructure with the following design: All my images are stored on S3, which is behind an nginx server. There are a lot of images in S3 in webp format. However on browser they are coming with content-type binary/octet-stream instead of image/webp. This is because S3 doesn't have support for image/webp mime type. What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set the appropriate Content-Type header for the object(s) in question. I'm not sure where you got your information that S3 cannot support image/webp.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C spec, images normally get mime-sniffed regardless of what is declared in the server response Content-Type header.